# Проект C# предназначен для платформы .NetFramework = v.4.6.1, а установлена v.4.6.1

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Возникла странная проблема[image: Ошибка]

Не совсем понятно как ее решить если требуется версия 4.6.1. а установлена версия 4.6.1.

Comment: Установлен по умолчанию пакет Windows 10 DotNet 4.6.1, устанавливаемый пакет DotNetFramework for VisualStudio 4.6.1 c установленным (пакетом) версией  фреймворка вы можете только исполнить запустить скомпилированный проект.

Comment: @DigitalCore: Почему не как ответ?

Comment: @VladD оформил как ответ, (писал с телефона комментарий).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Установлен по умолчанию пакет Windows 10 [Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=49982). Устанавливаемый пакет [Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.1 for VisualStudio (Developer Pack)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49978). 
С установленным пакетом-версией .NET Framework вы можете только исполнить, запустить скомпилированный проект.

Comment: Еще такая ошибка возникает когда не установлена нужная целевая платформа в свойствах проекта. Нужно зайти в свойства->приложения->целевая платформа и выбрать нужную.